# During second language acquisition, is it common for the speech organs to get tired by speaking the second language?

Tags: phonetics, language-acquisition, second-lang-acquisition, articulation

I am a non-native speaker of English (I'd rather not say what my native language is). I have noticed that my speech organs (tongue, lips, jaws and also the palate but I'm not so sure if it's the palate) get tired while speaking English for a while. It does not happen when I'm speaking my native language. I suspect it is because my speech organs are not acclimated to the movements they perform for articulating the sounds/ consonant clusters/ patterns of sounds of English.

Is it common for second language learner's speech organs to get tired while speaking the second language? How often does it happen cross-linguistically

Comment: In my own personal experience, yes, perfectly common, until you get used to it. I tend to get it when speaking a language with lots of /r/’s, like Icelandic or Spanish. I have no trouble producing /r/, but it does strain my tongue more than it would if it were a native phoneme to me.

Comment: An effect contributing to the fatigue is surely over-articulation in the foreign language. Native speakers tend to be lazy in their articulation (and know exactly when to do so).

Comment: As with any novel use of muscles, there is a period of tiredness from unaccustomed use. But it passes. In time you'll get to be just as sloppy as native speakers and it will be a relief.